# Determine point from one aspect ratio to an equivlent aspect ratio

Tags: percentages, ratio

I am working on a code program and get the X and Y coordinates of my cursor. My aspect ratio is 1280x720 and a point I am using for an example is (710, 300) however my x and y values must be 0.0-1.0, so I found the equivalent ratio to 1280x720 to be 1.0.5625, but now **I need the equation to convert my given point (710,300) to an equivalent one inside the aspect ratio 1.0x0.5625**

Comment: For the maximum coordinates, $1280 \overset{/1280}\longmapsto 1$ and $720 \overset{/1280}\longmapsto 0.5625$. Similarly, to scale your example point: $710 \overset{/1280}\longmapsto ?$ and $300 \overset{/1280}\longmapsto ?$ ?

Comment: Did not think it would be such a simple answer, thank you